# Excel Count with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, countif, multiple-conditions

I have a table with initial public offerings of companies from 1970 until 2008. These companies are part of different industries based on SIC indentifier codes (for example 3144 for a specific manufacturing industry). A company can operate in up to 39 industries (so 39 columns with an identifier)

I now want to create a table where I count the number of initial public offerings based on the year of the offering and the company being in a specific industry (so for example count all IPOs in 1975 in the 3144 code). Its works with Countif but the formula gets super long because for the SIC code conditions I need 38 OR formulas to say that the SIC code can lie in any of the 39 columns.

Is there a faster way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm assuming you have the year in column A and then SIC codes anywhere in columns B to AN

Try using `SUMPRODUCT`like this to count 3144 in 1975

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A1000=1975)*(B2:AN1000=3144))`

Assumes up to 1000 rows of data, change as required

You may need quotes arounnd "3144" in the formula if those columns are text formatted

Comment: Might have to be `=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A2:A1000)=1975)*(B2:AN1000=3144))`. With no sample data and vague details it's just a guessing game.